# Website can't access class in runtime

Tags: javascript, c#

I have Javascript as below where I'm reading a value from a class.
It works fine during dev and debug, but when I make the site live on the prod server it complains that:

> c:\path\mypage.ascx(8): error CS0103: The name 'setup' does not exist in the current context

I have:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SetValues() {
        var lookupValue = "<%=setup.Rate().ToString() %>";
                    }
```

and then:

```
public static class setup
{
    public static double Rate()
    {
         ...
         string sql = "SELECT Rate" +
                      "FROM Setup";
         DataRow dr = data.ExecuteDataSet(sql).Tables[0].Rows[0];
         if (dr == null)
             return 0;
         else
             return (double)dr["Rate"];
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is `setup` class inside a namespace?

Comment: No, it's not in a namespace

Comment: is the javascript Code on the ASPX or on the ASCX control?

Comment: It is in the ascx control.

Comment: @user1208908 Do you mean the class is defined inside the definition of the user control class? If so that's your problem, prefix with the user control name.

Comment: You need to use the fully qualified namespace path for the class `setup`.

Comment: The class is not in the ascx control, only the javascript.  
If I should use the fully qualified name would it not fail in design time as well?